# Trying to handle menu and movies

Tags: c#

I have 2 C# questions:

- Question 1: how do I get 20 movies with highest rating?
- Question 2: how do I make a menu in this?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;

namespace XXSlutuppgift_Movie { 
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<Movie> movieCollection = GetMovieCollection();
            List<Movie> Orderedlist = movieCollection.OrderBy(Film => Film.name).ToList();
            List<Movie> Top20MovieRating = movieCollection.OrderBy(Film => Film.rating).ToList();
            List<Movie> MovieYear = movieCollection.OrderBy(Film => Film.year).ToList();
            List<Movie> LetterSearch = movieCollection.OrderBy(Film => Film.name).ToList();

            static List<Movie> GetMovieCollection() {
                List<Movie> list = new List<Movie>();
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/moviecollection.xml");
                XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/MovieCollection/Movies");
                foreach(XmlNode row in node.ChildNodes) {
                    Movie item = new Movie();
                    item.id = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Id").InnerText);
                    item.name = row.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
                    item.rating = Double.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Rating").InnerText.Replace(".", ","));
                    item.votes = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Votes").InnerText);
                    item.year = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Year").InnerText);
                    list.Add(item);
                }
            return list
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put your whole question into the title!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to know how to post questions from [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), Regarding your question the full picture if you have a list and want return data from higher to lower you would get it as shown in below code:

```
        var list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(4);
        list.Add(5);
        list.Add(6);

        var desNumber=list.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

In your case if you have object called Movie that contains ratting property and want to get top 20 movie you can use take method which specify number of taken objects from list:

```
        var movieList = new GetMovieList();
        var topRatedMovies = movieList.OrderByDescending(m => m.Ratting).Take(20);
```

While GetMovieList() is a method that return List of Movie.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed you code :

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Xml; 
using System.Linq; 
namespace XXSlutuppgift_Movie 
{ 
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Movie> movieCollection = GetMovieCollection();
            List<Movie> Orderedlist = movieCollection.OrderBy(Film => Film.name).ToList();
            List<Movie> Top20MovieRating = movieCollection.OrderBy(Film => Film.rating).ToList();
            List<Movie> MovieYear = movieCollection.OrderBy(Film => Film.year).ToList();
            List<Movie> LetterSearch = movieCollection.OrderBy(Film => Film.name).ToList();
        }

        static List<Movie> GetMovieCollection() 
        { 
            List<Movie> list = new List<Movie>(); 
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
            doc.Load(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/moviecollection.xml"); 
            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/MovieCollection/Movies"); 
            foreach(XmlNode row in node.ChildNodes) 
            { 
                Movie item = new Movie(); 
                item.id = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Id").InnerText); 
                item.name = row.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText; 
                item.rating = Double.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Rating").InnerText.Replace(".", ",")); 
                item.votes = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Votes").InnerText); 
                item.year = Int32.Parse(row.SelectSingleNode("Year").InnerText); 
                list.Add(item); 
            } return list; 
        } 
    }
    public class Movie
    {
        public int id { get;set;}
        public string name { get;set;}
        public double rating { get;set;}
        public int votes { get;set;}
        public int year { get;set;}

    }
}
```